# What will use less CPU ticks: insertBefore vs innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome, browser

I've got a few hundreds items list that I need to regularly ajax update and display on mobile devices (mobile wekbkit browsers predominantly). It's easier for me to generate the entire list server side and update user's screen with `innerHTML`. The list is mainly picture thumbnails. I don't want the screen to flicker too much or be too much of a drag on their little mobile CPUs. My question is: what performs better in case of updating `<ul>` list, `insertBefore` + client side sorting or `innerHTML` of entire list?

Comment: jsperf.com is a great place to test this kind of stuff.

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml **or** http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-element-innerhtml-vs-insertbefore-newelement

Comment: To achieve best performance minimize the number of HTTP requests and DOM manipulations. Ideally, you want to make one Ajax request to retrieve the HTML source code, and one DOM manipulation operation to append the source code to your page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best answer is: Write it both ways and profile it on your target browsers.

However, in my previous experiments with this, I've generally found that when doing a big update, `innerHTML` was markedly faster than working through the DOM interface. Which makes sense: Fundamentally, browsers parse HTML into their internal structures and display the result. It's their raison d'être, and they're highly optimized for doing that. In contrast, lots of DOM calls require lots of trips across the JavaScript/browser internals interface, through an API that may or may not be a good fit for the internal structures of the browser. Of course, the picture today is quite different from a few years ago; DOM updates are much more common and much faster than they used to be.

But again, this stuff varies so much based on what you're doing and your target browsers that it's best to create a representative test each way and look at it empirically.

Answer (score 0):

1. That would depend on the browser's implementation, there is no definition or even rule of thumb for this.
2. I doubt very much that anyone would notice a difference.

So just pick the one you are most comfortable with and don't waste precious time debating this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this page: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html and on a couple of mobile devices run the tests and get some numbers.

But, if you are concerned about performance, why not sort on the server-side the send it over to the client, so then each node can be added with either method, but the mobile device doesn't have to sort.

Answer (score 0):

If you need performance you can do it in this way

1. remove the parent node from the DOM tree (the UL or the parent of the UL....)
2. add all children (LI) to the list via insertBefore or innerHTML. innerHTML is faster
3. add the parent to the DOM.

why remove the parent from the DOM? Performance! The Browser renders only two time the page. Otherwise it will render the page for each DOM manipulation - each insert!